# How can I remove the space around my background-colored header in an html page?

Tags: html, css

I just started building a webpage using `html` and made a simple header for it. I want the header to be exactly along the borders of the screen but there is a white space all around my header. This is how it looks:
[image]

I changed my `css` by setting the `margin`, `border` and `outline` of my header to 0. But this doesn't seem to do the work and the white space is still there. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1{
            margin:0 auto;
            padding:20px;
            border:0;
            outline:0;
            background: #003399;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: "Calibri";
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>This is my website.</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out what my error is. Please anyone help. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You should set it to your `body` tag. It has `padding` by default.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it was that simple. It worked.

Comment: You can use the dev tools to find whether an element has padding/margin and what's their width or height. https://www.bu.edu/tech/services/cccs/websites/www/wordpress/how-to/find-area-width/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all my projects I place this code just at the start of my CSS files:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

So I have more control about margins, paddings and sizes (`box-sizing: border-box` makes borders and padding being applied inside the container size, not as an extra size, so it's easier to play with percentage sizes).

Another option is to put [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io) before your styles, that already includes usual corrections like these.

Answer (score 1):

By default `body` tag take some CSS, just add following css for this

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: just fyi, if the value is `0px` you can remove the "px" notation.